# Ubuntu Server 18.04 Freeze with crazy screen

Tags: linux, ubuntu, freeze, kernel-panic

I have a server setup with Ubuntu Server 18.04 it works perfectly fine but after about 20-30 hours uptime the system feezes completely. No services on any ports reply. Plugging a monitor into the box gives the login prompt as it should and once the freeze happens the attached image occurs.

How can I go about diagnosing this? I have already ran a memory check for 4 full passes and got a 100 percent pass rate.

[Monitor photograph after freeze](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RD9H3.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend doing basic hardware diagnostics. Since you aren't using Windows, I've found some links to Ubuntu Questions for that.

https://askubuntu.com/questions/389084/system-testing-tool-for-ubuntu

https://askubuntu.com/questions/109935/are-there-any-hardware-diagnostic-tools

This link below is about fixing a failed upgrade, but the steps seem relevant to any possible OS repair scenario.

https://askubuntu.com/questions/748289/how-to-repair-ubuntu-installation-after-interrupted-dist-upgrade-without-losing

The askubuntu.com site is part of the StackExchange family of sites, so you might want to consider asking there, since it might get your some better answers. Because it focuses on Linux, specifically Ubuntu, you're more likely to get the experts who actually know what they're talking about. This forum is a mix of Windows, Mac, Linux, Android, Arduino, Raspberry Pi, and other systems.